# Advanced Counting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet that counts candidates that have gained work in a certain country, but each job (`Company`) is liked to another sheet with a sector attached.

I need to be able to count if the applicant lives in certain `Country` and the sector the `Company` sits in and each table is collected Monthly. I don't know if this can be achieved with a `COUNTIF` function or if I need to look down the route of `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP`

My Database:

```
****************************************************
*   Name  *  Country  *   Company   *  Start Date  *
****************************************************
*  John   *  Brazil   *     Gap     *  21/03/2016  *
* Jessica *    USA    * Burger King *  21/02/2016  *
****************************************************
```

Sector Sheet:

```
***************************
*   Company   *  Sector   *
***************************
*     Gap     *  Retail   *
* Burger King * Catering  *
***************************
```

Data collection table:

```
********************************************
*   FEB 2016   *  Brazil  *   USA   *  UK  *
********************************************
*    Retail:   *     0    *    0    *  0   *
********************************************
*  Catering:   *     0    *    1    *  0   *
********************************************
```

Any assistance on where to look would be amazing and apologies if there is a simple function to find this data

Comment: Do you know `COUNTIFS`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT() would be a better fit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$3=K$1)*(MONTH($D$2:$D$3)=MONTH($J$1))*(YEAR($D$2:$D$3)=YEAR($J$1))*(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$3,$C$2:$C$3,$G$2:$G$3,$J2)))
```

[image]

Once put in the upper left cell of the matrix and the correct references are used, then drag across and down.  Pay attention to the `$` notation that makes the various absolute.

I had to remove the `:` on the third table data.  The data has to match perfectly or it will not count.

Comment: Amazing! This is perfect except if one of the "Country" fields is blank it causes the #N/A error and sometimes I may not enter the Country right away. Really sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Then wrap the whole thin in an IFERROR(),`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$3=K$1)*(MONTH($D$2:$D$3)=MONTH($J$1))*(YEAR($D$2:$D$3)=YEAR($J$1))*(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$3,$C$2:$C$3,$G$2:$G$3,$J2))),0)`.  Remember to mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, you are brilliant